# Bash script to scan through folder and and delete zeros in each file

Tags: bash, for-loop, recursion, zero-pad

I have a folder consisting of 68 files (.txt files ) out of which 38 files have zeros starting from fourth row and ending in third column.

i would like to remove all the zeros from the files by using a bash script.

The .txt files are in following format ( i am attaching pictures of first three files in my directory ), you can see the for each file a new row with additional number of zeros was added.

Few examples of the files are listed below

```
regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt

667869 667869.000000 
580083 580083.000000 
316133 316133.000000



regional_vol_GM_atlas2.txt

667869 667869.000000 
580083 580083.000000 
316133 316133.000000 
0 0.000000 
9020 9020.000000  
11065 11065.000000 



 regional_vol_GM_atlas3.txt

667869 667869.000000 
580083 580083.000000 
316133 316133.000000 
0 0.000000 
0 0.000000 
11651 11651.000000 

regional_vol_GM_atlas3.txt

667869 667869.000000 
580083 580083.000000 
316133 316133.000000 
0 0.000000 
0 0.000000 
0 0.000000 
12706 12706.000000
```

for 38th file, 37 rows of zeros were padded starting from row three, how can i remove them through script ? the common file format of all the files in directory is regional_vol_GM_atlas*.txt

Comment: is there common pattern for file naming ? like `file1.txt ,file2.txt ... `?

Comment: [Please do not post code screenshots.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Paste code instead.

Comment: @PS. the common file patter is regional_vol_GM_atlas1,regional_vol_GM_atlas2,regional_vol_GM_atlas3,..etc, the file ends with  regional_vol_GM_atlas38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove lines like `0 0.0000` from the 3rd line AND trailing zeroes (and the dot) of last field like this:

```
sed -i -e '3,$ {/0 0\.0\+/d;}' -e 's/\.0\+ *$//' regional*txt
```

before:

```
4536 23452345.0000
0 0.0000
```

after:

```
4536 23452345
```

(dot + 1 or more zeroes at the end of the line, changed by "nothing")

warning: this is "in-place". Make a backup before trying this. It does not count how many columns are there. If this is a problem, then `awk` should be used.

(make a test not in-place like this: `sed -e '3,$ {/0 0\.0\+/d;}' -e 's/\.0\+ *$//' one_of_your_files.txt`)

Recursive case: if files are in several subdirs apply `sed` on the result of the `find` command:

```
sed -e '3,$ {/0 0\.0\+/d;}' -e 's/\.0\+ *$//' $(find subdir_root -type f -name "regional*.txt")
```

Comment: But how i can scan through entire directory and delete the zeros , its not one file, there are 38 files like this and 38th file, there are 37 rows of Zeros padded, how can i delete them all,

Comment: I do not see any change i have run the query but no change in the files

Comment: @DevanDevak: if your flavour of `sed` doesn't understand `-i` option, replace `sed -i ` by `perl -pi -e `.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre        There is a space at the end of the line in each file

Comment: @DevanDevak: could be it. On MacOSX it is the case. Could not see the space on the screeshots :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I use ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Unfortunately, the screen shots were remove and i copied and pasted the data inside the files, i did not check it that there are spaces in files, only after you suggested , i have rechecked them

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Yes i can remove the .0000 from the files but i also need to remove the zeros starting third row in each file

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, How can i possibly remove the Zeros starting in third row of each file, should i write a loop that scans through the entire directory and removes zeros in each files?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , Yes, but as you can see from the file output, for each file, the number of rows increases proportionally, for example for second file, i have 1 row with 0 0.000000,  but in third file , i have 2 rows with 0 0.000000, for 38th files , i have 37 rows with 0 0.000000, i need remove them all

Comment: I'll figure out something later, I have to go now. grep could help but can be done with sed too.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I will work on it, but your input is greatly appreciated

Comment: See my edits. I added a command to remove `0 0.00000` lines from the 3rd line. Should be complete now.